# Specman - how can I use define exp as string in macro?

Tags: macros, specman

I have the following define (and more):

```
define d_buff1_en_adc0_s 'LV_TOP_TB/LV_TOP_inst//CAFE_MPW_TOP_inst/D_BUFF1_en_ADC0';
```

I have the following macro:

```
 define <force_and_check'action> "force_and_check <signal_f'exp> <signal_c'exp> <ip_name'exp> <val_signal_f'num> <init_val_signal_f'num>" as {
   force <signal_f'exp> = <val_signal_f'num>;
   wait[2];
   check that <signal_c'exp>_s == <val_signal_f'num> else dut_errorf("%s Connectivity Error! %s is %b, but should be %b" ,<ip_name'exp>, **<signal_c'exp>**, <signal_c'exp>_s, <val_signal_f'num>);   
   force <signal_f'exp> = <init_val_signal_f'num>;
};
```

Example of using the macro:
force_and_check 'adc_s_event[4]' d_buff1_en_adc0_s "CAFE" 1'b1 1'b0;

I want to present the  (the bold one ** **) int the dut_errorf as string (for eample as d_buff1_en_adc0_s)... How can I do it? (not it present as the value of the define in hexa)

Answer (score 0):

Just put it inside double quotes as part of the string:

```
check that <signal_c'exp>_s == <val_signal_f'num>
else dut_errorf("%s Connectivity Error! <signal_c'exp> is %b, but should be %b", <ip_name'exp>, <signal_c'exp>_s, <val_signal_f'num>);
```